# Javascript/Perl Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the difference between `(?: )` and `(?= )`  I assume that the first returns the text that it matches in a match function (but doesn't when applied to a sub expression group number, but not sure if I am right. Thank in advance :-) I know what they are used for, but I am not sure how they act differently.  Also can repetition characters be applied to look ahead assertions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing about both of these constructs is that the *don't* return anything. `(?: ... )` is used the same way as ordinary `( ... )` except that its result is not captured and not returned. In Perl, and I believe in Javascript, this can lead to faster performance due to the Regex engine not having to remember the matched substrings.

The idea of `(?= )` is different. You can think of any component of a regex as sort of "eating up" some subset of the matched string. But not with `(?= )`. Another way to think of it is that whatever comes *after* the `(?= )` matches at the exact same place in the string that the `(?= )` itself matches, not after the end of it like a normal group.

Comment: What do u mean when you say not returned?

Comment: It's the difference between capturing `()` and non-capturing `(?:)` groups. With non-capturing you cannot find out afterwards what text from the source matched that particular subpattern, only that it must have matched if the whole pattern matched.

Answer (score 3):

`(?: )` creates a group that **won't** be captured, i.e. stored in any back references. It usually used where you need a group but don't care about having it in a capturing group. This increases performance and unclutters backreferences.

`(?= )` is a lookahead assertion. It is used to look for something whilst not consuming any characters as a match.